# jQuery draggable with position conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Trying to figure out how to be able to drag the red square ONLY AFTER the blue square has been dragged to the other end of its parent.

Also wondering if it is possible (in a separate scenario) to have the red square mirror the blue square when the blue square is dragged.

https://jsfiddle.net/t167y2ga/14/

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable_left").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#draggable_right").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stop` event:

```
stop:function(ev,ui){
        if(ui.position.left === 150) {
            $("#draggable_right").draggable({
            containment: "parent",
          });

    }
```

Something like this will do the first part:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jo63eeg/)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your first goal

> be able to drag the red square ONLY AFTER the blue square has been
>   dragged to the other end of its parent

You just need to apply the `draggable` to the html element after the [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) is fired from the first `draggable` element. Sample code is:

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable_left").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $("#draggable_right").draggable({
        containment: "parent",
      });
    },
  });
});
```

See [the JSFiddle working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/apjgL0vy/)

**EDIT:** In case you want to disable the `draggable` when blue element is not in the right side, see this [other JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpvt6g0y/)